# QGIS 3 Show Red Vertex Crosses in Edit Mode

Tags: qgis

I don't know if this is a change in QGIS 3 or if I managed to turn it off somewhere, but in previous versions of QGIS when a layer was in edit mode there were red crosses on all the vertices.

I would like to have that again, I'm using 3.6. I imagine it is in settings somewhere but I can't find it!

Answer (score 1):

Open `Settings > Options > Digitizing`. You will find **Vertex marker style**.

You may have changed it either to `Semi transparent circle` or `None`.

[image]

Comment: But this only shows the markers for the selected objects, not for all the objects as with previous QGIS versions. Can that be done in 3?

Comment: You can change `Show markers only for selected features` option. Default is ON as the one shown in the picture I have posted above.